# ansible user current user in configuration

Tags: ansible

I am using ansible to configure the several computers after installation.

For this I run ansible locally on the machines. The "main" user on the installation has often a different name. I want to use that user for variables like `become_user`. The "main" user is also the user, who calls `ansible-playbook`.

So can I somehow set "become_user" to the user who called `ansible-playbook`?

Comment: Use `remote_user` instead of `become_user` to connect remote side. `become_user` is for privilege escalation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not sure why you need to set `become_user` to user you are already running your playbook with, but you can use `env` lookup to get `USER` environment variable:

```
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - debug: msg="{{ lookup('env','USER') }}"
```

Comment: @AK why? The OP needs username env in his playbook (although I don't understand what for) – I give him an option. And stressed that he shouldn't user become_user in this way.

Comment: Wonderful solution!

Answer (score 2):

You can logon locally on control host as 'nathan', but want to connect to other servers as user 'ansible' (better in ansible.cfg)

```
remote_user = ansible
```

If you want on remote host connect as 'ansible' and perform one task as root or apache -- then sudo to root (apache or other user) you should use `become_user` for this particular task.

Please note also, than remote server may NOT have such user as on control host! (In common way)

In your particular case if you logon locally as 'nathan' and want to connect to 'remote' server as 'nathan' you should omit both `remote_user` and `become_user`: just logon with your current credentials!

For example, there's two sysadminst in organization: nathan and peter -- so, there's two workstation (heidelberg-nathan and berlin-peter) as ansible control host and thousands clients. Both nathan and peter connect to remote side as nathan or peter and perform tasks. Each of them can non-password sudoers to perform admin tasks.

PS Ok, let's test both solution (first - from Konstantin Suvorov's answer, second -- from knowhy's answer).

My control host berlin-ansible-01, i'm logged in as 'nathan'. Remote client is host berlin-client-01. I will log into client host as user 'ansible'.

My ansible.cfg is:

```
[defaults]
sudo_flags=-HE
hash_behaviour = merge
retry_files_enabled = false
log_path = ./main.log
ask_vault_pass=true
remote_user = ansible
```

Playbook is simple:

```
- name: test
  hosts: '{{ target }}'
  tasks:
    - debug: msg="step 1 = {{ lookup('env','USER') }}"
    - setup:
    - debug: msg="step 2 = {{ hostvars[target].ansible_env.USER }}"
#more than one client in taget needs iterate items:
#    - debug: msg="step 2 = {{ hostvars[item].ansible_env.USER }}"
#      with_items: "{{ hostvars }}"
```

Let's run it:

> ```
> [nathan@berlin-ansible-01 stackoverflow]$ ansible-playbook -i hosts_staging test.yml --extra-vars "target=berlin-client-01"
> Vault password:
>
> PLAY [test] ********************************************************************
>
> TASK [setup] *******************************************************************
> ok: [berlin-client-01]
>
> TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
> ok: [berlin-client-01] => {
>     "msg": "step 1 = nathan"
> }
>
> TASK [setup] *******************************************************************
> ok: [berlin-client-01]
>
> TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
> ok: [berlin-client-01] => {
>     "msg": "step 2 = ansible"
> }
>
> PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
> berlin-client-01             : ok=4    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
> ```

Comment: OP _ run ansible locally on the machines_

Comment: @KonstantinSuvorov Sure, but this incorrect _in common way_. I've added an remark to question.

Answer (score 1):

`ansible-playbook` provides the `--become-user` CLI flag along with `--ask-become-pass` (if needed).

In most cases, this is a bad setup. You should standardize the `user` on all of your machines else you'll have to maintain certs/passwords for each user separately.

Comment: Thanks! The user names are different because I am using ansible for private setup of computers. It is not what it is intended for, but still works very good.

Comment: I realized that :-)

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to set `become_user` when the playbook should run with the user who started `ansible-playbook`

[become](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/become.html) is for privilege escalation. If I got this question right privilege escalation is not needed.

The name of the user which runs the playbook is available as an `ansible fact` `{{ ansible_env.username }}`

Comment: You're right about privilege escalation. Facts are gathered on remote side, so your solution is suitable only for case when control host is same as client host (see details in my answer)